# How would I automatically execute a git pull after a commit?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, pull

I have a server running Jenkins with a repository setup holding a directory within the server so that when I travel, I can just pull changes on my laptop and push any others. However, when I want to push changes, it does push to GitHub and Jenkins, but doesn't update the server files itself. How would I set this up to where the server will automatically pull changes from Jenkins/Github to the server files?

Directory is holding many folders with zip files. Changes would include new folders/new zip files within folders. As of now, I have to use PuTTy via FTP to manually pull any changes from Jenkins/Github.

Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for the server, Jenkins ver. 1.590.

Comment: Pulling won't be enough will it? You need to update as well? Couldn't you just create a script that pulls and then updates and set this up to run periodically?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bitbucket this [link](http://brandonsummers.name/blog/2012/02/10/using-bitbucket-for-automated-deployments/) suggest good solution,I used it and it is very good.